# Moment js add month

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I got an error while trying to add month to a given date. I am not sure if it is an error or bug. Here is the code i'm trying.

```js
    var date = moment('2019-06-22');
    var addMonth = moment(date).add(1,'M').calendar();
    //Output: 07/22/2019

    var date = moment('2019-06-23');
    var addMonth = moment(date).add(1,'M').calendar();
    //ouput: Last Tuesday at 12:00 AM
```

Comment: As documented in [calendar-time](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/) of moment `calendar()` **displays time relative to a given referenceTime (defaults to now)**. So use `format('YYYY-MM-DD')` instead of `calendar()`.

Answer (score -1):

Use this,it works for me,

let addedMonth=moment("2019-06-01").add(1, 'months').calendar();

console.log("Add months ::::",addedMonth);

or,

let addedMonth=moment("2019-06-01").add(1, 'M').calendar();

console.log("Add months ::::",addedMonth);

these both way can be used to add month.

Comment: Please read Naveen Kumar H S comment first. The answer given is not correct.